# Query - SQL Server com stuff

Tags: mysql, sql-server, query

Galera, na consulta abaixo quero que traga a da seguinte maneira.

> ```
> contato
> andreia, marcos, juliana
> ```

ou seja, na mesma linha. Na consulta, utilizei o `stuff`, porém, sem sucesso. Hoje ela está trazendo dessa forma.

> ```
> contato
>
> andreia
> marcos
> juliana
> ```

Segue a consulta:

```
--Contatos vinculados a contas cadastradas de 17/11/2015 até hoje, sem oportunidades cadastradas--

select distinct
U.UsuID Usuid, 
U.UsuNome Nome_Fantasia, U.UsuRazaoSocial Razão_Social, 
A.Descricao ABC,
U.UsuCGC CNPJ,
t.UsuNome,
U.UsuUF,
U.UsuCidade,
CP.CompDesc Qtde_CNPJs,
R.RamoDesc,
contato = STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + t1.UsuNome
              FROM usuario t1
              WHERE t1.UsuID = ur.UsuID
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 1, 1, '')
from CRMDetalhesConta DCT
left join Usuario U
on (U.UsuID = DCT.ContaID)
left join CRMDetalhesContato DCO
on (DCT.ContaID = DCO.ContaID)
left join Usuario UR
on (UR.UsuID = DCO.ContatoID)
INNER JOIN ComplementoColunas C ON U.UsuID = C.UsuID AND C.LinhaID  = 1 
                                                     AND CompID     = 32 
                                                     AND C.ColunaID = 12
LEFT JOIN Complemento  CP     ON CP.UsuID = U.UsuID  AND CP.CompID  = 1
INNER JOIN Usuario      T     ON t.UsuID = c.ColunaValor
LEFT JOIN CRMRamo           R ON R.RamoID = DCT.RamoID
LEFT JOIN  CurvaABC     A     ON A.CurvaID = U.CurvaID
where t.UsuID in (38)
      AND U.UsuRazaoSocial IS NOT NULL  
      AND u.EmpLiberada= 1 AND U.UsuTipo = 'C' 
      AND U.UsuID NOT IN (select UsuIDCliente from Tarefa where TarTipID in (710) and TarStatus in (0,1,5))
      AND U.UsuID not in (select UsuIDCliente from Tarefa where TarTipID in (710) and CONVERT(DATE,TarFechamento) BETWEEN '01-01-2018' and getdate())
      and u.UsuID = 83295
order by U.UsuID
```

Comment: pode posta mais detalhe do seu resultado hoje ... para as colunas U.UsuID Usuid, 
U.UsuNome Nome_Fantasia, U.UsuRazaoSocial Razão_Social, 
A.Descricao ABC,
U.UsuCGC CNPJ,
t.UsuNome,
U.UsuUF,
U.UsuCidade,
CP.CompDesc Qtde_CNPJs,
R.RamoDesc,
contato

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/545672/2740371

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, os outros campos nao interferem.